When I rotate the bone on its axis, part of my mesh scales instead of rotating properly
I'm trying to rig a drone. When I parent the fan part to the bone and rotate it, it doesn't rotate on its axis. Instead, it scales weirdly. I'm new to rigging.
How can I make the fan rotate correctly on its axis?



The vertices of the fan are part of several vertex groups, see for example for this one:

Select all the blades and remove from all groups:

Then assign to fan.L only:

